# How to empty response issue from any machine in AWS IoT?

Tags: protocol-buffers, mqtt, iot, aws-iot, aws-iot-core

Asin the Screenshots  I set up my whole AWS IoT Core Server as MQTT Broker  but I am getting an empty response from my machine  . any suggestions to solve this ??

[image: Topic Publish on IoT]

This response is in Hex format as default need to decrypt(decode) this using Protocol buffers files.

I am expecting number of fields as response like success status , slot number
,rl_type
,rl_mode
,rl_conn
,rl_status
,rl_csq
,rl_rsrp
,rl_sinr ect.

Comment: Any chance you could [edit] your question to share a [mcve] ([as **text**, not as a screen shot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)) showing some code that reproduces the problem?  From [ask]: *Help others reproduce the problem...  if your problem is with code you've written, you should include some...Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem.*

Answer (score 0):

AWS IoT Core now supports decoding protocol buffer directly within AWS IoT Rule Engine. Please have a look at the announcement here: https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2022/12/aws-iot-core-rules-engine-google-protocol-buffer-messaging-format/